# Mitigation for gvfs memory leak?

Tags: 18.04, gvfs, memory-leak

I have a workflow like this: I fire up my Win7 virtual machine, connect my smartphone, and run Samsung Smartswitch. This worked great in 14.04 LTS.

In 18.04 LTS...not so much.  There's a giant memory leak in `gvfsd-mtp` that hoovers up all 12G of my RAM and brings my system to a halt.

There are bugs related to this and I've reported another.  My question is, can there be any mitigation for this? Is there a way to fence in `gvfs` so it cannot use up all the RAM?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any news?

Comment: New kernel on 18.04 did not help. Neither did a workaround I found on superuser to limit memory use by process :(

Comment: In my case I can stop `gvfsd-mtp` process (`pkill -STOP gvfsd-mtp`) to avoid the memory increase.

Comment: Thanks. As I was writing this I realized I was probably doing the workaround wrong - I was limiting virtualbox and it should have been gvfs. I won't be able to try it again for a few days

Comment: I confirm the issue.

Comment: @Madh I was able to test this out and your workaround is successful. If you care to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop `gvfsd-mtp` process to avoid the memory increase:

```
pkill -STOP gvfsd-mtp
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be solved in upcoming release of gvfs (version 1.39.90, if I understand the version scheme). The fixing commit is [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/commit/63700b556522cb779fee9b7f45b869df6b178c68).

I had the same bug but with `gvfsd-google`, as I use GDrive as storage for Déjà Dup Backup.

Comment: 2021 and I'm still seeing this problem. Perhaps it's a different memory leak?

Comment: @JamesNewton 18.04 still has the 1.36.1 version of `gvfs` so it's still a problem there based on what this answer says.

Comment: I can confirm what @OrganicMarble says. Ubuntu 18.04 is still having old package version with the bug.